# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odac

So I have such a problem. There is a Windows App with Entiti Framework 5 model, Oracle database, client version is 11.2. My machine is Windows 8 Pro 64-bit, Visual Studio 2012. That app runs at server with no problems at all. However, when I run it on my local machine I have such Exception:

```
Type initializer "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory" thrown an exception. ---> 
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
```

I googled and searched for an answer here, I copied all dll's to a folder where exe-file is located. No luck. Both local and server have the same ODAC. both machines are 64-bit. Any fresh ideas would be helpful. Thank's in advance!

Comment: Do you get the problem in Visual Studio only, or when running the EXE?

Comment: I can't build it is Visual Studio. I only have source code from SVN.

Answer (score 0):

no one answer this question for so long time, let me tell you why, when you debug use visual studio, the iis express by default will use 32bit as standard, two ways can solve this issue:

> 1. install 32 bit ODAC 
>      https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html
> 2. enale iis express settings to 64 bit version:
>      vs2017 for example, tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions => Web Projects => Use the 64 bit version